# How to import a function from a third party library which is not exported in the index.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I want to import a function which is `exported` where it is defined but not in the index.js of the library.

For example, I want to import `doesHaveValue` [function](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/main/src/value_checker.ts) from cucumber.js.

I've node.js npm project. cucumber is installed using below command.

`$ npm install @cucumber/cucumber`

In my code, I'm importing the `doesHaveValue` as below -

`import {doesNotHaveValue} from '@cucumber/cucumber/lib/value_checker';`

But is there a better way to import this function?

Comment: You have to import from the file that exports it.